# Can we characterize all infinite Euclidean domains having exactly one invertible element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, soft-question, integral-domain, euclidean-algorithm

$\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ are two Euclidean domains having exactly one invertible element. My question is:

> Can we characterize all Euclidean domains $D$ having exactly one invertible element, i.e., $|D^{\times}|=1$ ?

For finite domains it is easy because any finite ED is an ID so a field, so the only one is $\mathbb Z_2$, but what about infinite Euclidean domains ? Please help. Thanks in advance

UPDATE : Obviously, as MooS has also noted, if $D$ is an ID with $|D^{\times}|=1$ then $D$ has characteristic $2$. Any progress regarding the problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: Any such domain clearly has characteristic $2$ and it should be easy to deal with the case, where $D$ is of finite type over $\mathbb F_2$. But there might be cases, where $D$ is not of finite type or can someone easily handle this?

Comment: @MooS What do you mean by finite type in this context?

Comment: @MooS : What is finite type ?

Comment: That it is a finitely generated $\mathbb F_2$-algebra. This is standard notation, isn't it?

Comment: @MooS Hmm, probably, though I usually only see the term when the thing in question is not itself the algebra (such as schemes of finite type). For some reason I was thinking finite representation type when I read it, which just seemed wrong.

Comment: Another easy observation is that every $a\in D\setminus\mathbb Z_2$ is transcendental over $\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling : yes I see , indeed , as $1=-1$ in $D$ , so $D$ contains (a copy of) $\mathbb Z_2$ and if $a \in D\setminus \mathbb Z_2$ is algebraic ( you mean integral right ?) over $\mathbb Z_2$ then $\mathbb Z_2[a]$ would be an integral domain which is integral over the field $\mathbb Z_2$ , so $\mathbb Z_2[a]$ itself would be a field contained in $D$ and since $\mathbb Z_2[a]$ has more than two elements , so it has more than one unit , thn $D$ would have more than one unit , contradiction!!

Comment: @ChristianRemling : If I have made correct interpretation of your comment then please reply , I will add it to the update of my  question

Comment: @user228169: Yes, this works. Actually, what I had in mind was the following: if we had $f(a)=0$ with an irreducible $f\in\mathbb Z_2[x]$, then the constant term is $1$ ($f$ isn't irreducible otherwise), so $a(a^{n-1} + \ldots + c_1) = 1$, so $a\in D^{\times}$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling : yeah off course , that's actually the proof that if $A$ is integral domain $B$ is a subdomain of $A$ and $A$ is integral over $B$ , then $A$ is a field iff $B$ is a field :)

Answer (score 3):

In their article "Principal ideal domains and Euclidean domains having 1 as the only unit" (Communications in Algebra, 2001), Heinzer and Roitman partially answer your question.  They show that a Euclidean domain that is *finitely generated* as a ring and has only one invertible element must be isomorphic to $\mathbb F_2$ or $\mathbb F_2[X]$. The question appears to be open when it comes to rings that are not finitely generated, however.